# Why would the Java compiler create a serialVersionUID synthetic field?

Tags: java, field, serialversionuid, synthetic

As part of debugging an application, I noticed that `Field.getDeclaredFields()` returns some synthetic fields, including a `serialVersionUID` field in a class extending an interface, although none extend `Serializable`.

Why does the compiler add such fields?

**UPDATE**

In fact, there is also a `$VRc` synthetic field created.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Java compiler/runtime will not automatically create a serialVersionUID field. I suspect that you are using some form of bytecode enchancement framework under the hood that is being instructed to add the synthetic fields either at runtime, or during compilation.

The `$VRc` field is produced by the Emma instrumentation framework, so that would be the reason for at least one of the synthetic fields.

The `serialVersionUID` field is also [added by Emma](http://emma.sourceforge.net/reference/ch03s02.html#prop-ref.instr.do_suid_compensation), when the `instr.do_suid_compensation` property is set to true.

Comment: You are right, I am indeed using Emma for test coverage. When I disactivate it, the fields are not there anymore.

Comment: Yes, even serialVersionUID is also [generated by Emma](http://emma.sourceforge.net/reference/ch03s02.html#prop-ref.instr.do_suid_compensation) if a certain property was set.

Answer (score 1):

This field is essential for Java [serialization](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/). In short: it allows the JVM to discover that the class that was serialized (e.g. saved on disk) has been changed afterwards and cannot be safely deserialized back to object.

Have a look at **Version Control** chapter in the document quoted above, it explains how `serialVersionUID` is used.

UPDATE: just noticed your class does not implement `Serializable`. Are you sure none of super classes or implemented interfaces aren't extending `Serializable`?

Comment: I think the question is more about why the field got added when none of the classes in the inheritence hierarchy implement the `Serializable` interface, not what the purpose of the field is.

Comment: Yes, 100% sure. It is similar to class A implements B and B is declared as an interface. A and B don't declare any fields themselves. That's it.. (and no, this is not about the meaning/use of serial version UIDs)